# Can I store Lat and Long for searching from Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I put a screen in my app to allow the user can enter their location. They can use their current location or an address. The screen will have a google map, the user can pin an address on the map. I wish to store the location(lat/long) from Map or Google Geolocation from Google API. Using those lat/long in sql search in another screen without google map. Is it against the google map terms and conditions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (Terms of Use), not coding.

Answer (score 0):

From the official ToS:

> No caching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store
>   any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store
>   limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency
>   (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking
>   usage), and only if such storage:
>
> - is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
> - is secure;
> - does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
> - does not modify attribution in any way.

[Paragraph 10.5 d](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)

Comment: Can I save the lat/long the user just pressed on the map?